# NodeJS module.exports submodule

Tags: javascript, node.js

Folks,
  Trying to include other .js files to be able to export from a module in the following manner.  This will make the main module more readable.  I am trying to include code from other functions.

I suppose its not the correct way.  Can someone guide me in the right direction?

main module file:

```
module.exports = {
    eval(fs.readFileSync('./extras/foo.js')+'');

    fdsa: function (barf, callback) {
    },
    asdf: function (barf, callback) {
    },
}
```

foo.js:

```
foo: function (barf, callback) {
     ...
     callback(err, result);
}
```

Comment: Just make foo.js a module that exports functions.  Then in main file var foo = require('./extras/foo');

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: so if other functions call the main.js, how would they use the submodule of main called foo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want **main.js** to basically duplicate and enhance everything foo has (which is silly, but that seems to be what you are asking), you can do this:

**main.js**

```
var foo = require('./extras/foo');
for (var prop in foo) {
  exports[prop] = foo[prop];
}
exports.fdsa = function(...
exports.asdf = function(...
```

**./extras/foo.js**

```
exports.foo = function(...
```

Side note if you put a file in `somedir/index.js`, it can be required as just `somedir`, which can also be useful.

If you just want access to `foo` by way of main and are OK with a sub-namespace, just do:

**main.js**

```
exports.foo = require('./extras/foo');
```

Then your calling code can do:

```
require('./main').foo.foo(blah, callback);
```

Also note if you want the entire `foo` module to be a function, just do:

```
module.exports = function foo(barf, callback) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simple way to achieve this with es6 module pattern.
So in foo.js

```
export function foo(barf, callback) {
     ...
     callback(err, result);
}
```

And in main.js you will have something like,

```
export * from './foo.js';
export function fdsa(barf, callback) {
...
}
```